# What is best approach to sync data between 1000 wpf(with offline mode) / SQL Server app to central website (SQL Server ) and vice versa?

Tags: c#, sql-server

We have an online food ordering management system with 1000 registered restaurants in this application. Every restaurant has its own product, category.

I want to create another desktop WPF application named Epos (Electronic point of sale). This application has both an online and offline mode. I am concerned about the data sync between 1000 the customer epos and the central, online food ordering system. If an order is placed from a desktop PC it should sync to website. If any customer order is placed using the website it should sync to their desktop app.

Website: Asp.net mvc and SQL Server database
Desktop Epos: WPF app plus SQL Server Express
We saw some solutions on the internet :

Microsoft Sync Framework
What is the best approach to solve this problem?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: why doesn't each client use the main database (either directly or via an api)?

Comment: Sync framework is good if your desktop app needs an "offline mode." If it's online I agree with the others, why not just access the central db?

Comment: if internet is down in client site we want to store data into locally. if internet return client data should sync to website

Comment: You have restaurants with unreliable Internet?

Comment: yes we have some  restaurants with unreliable Internet

Comment: Wow, you have really complicated the solution if that is a requirement.  Clearly they cannot place an order while the Internet is down.

Answer (score 0):

Too broad but most likely you don't even need db on client

I would just load the objects in a List and use LINQ
Unless you have some really massive List

I would just synch down by demand on the client
And have it synch everytime it uploads an order

You can also have a watch on the db to get notified but not sure how that would work with a service

If the Internet went down you would still have what is in memory so you cannot shut the app down.  But I am amazed you have restaurants with unreliable Internet.  Do they have reliable power?